# Jest test not updating the DOM when testing out a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

In my test, I have create a function called postData that returns mock json data via a Promise. I use this to test out the urlValidation function which uses postData function to add the json data into the DOM. I also added the DOM inside the test as well.

**testUrl.spec.js**

```js
import { urlValidation } from '../client/js/urlValidation';
import { printData } from '../client/js/checkStatement';


test('Testing url Validation', () => {

 document.body.innerHTML = `
 <body>

 <header>
     <div class="logo">
         Logo
     </div>
     <div class="title">
         Title
     </div>
     <div class="menu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Body</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Footer</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </header>

 <main>
     <section class="form-section">
         <form class="blog-entry-text" onsubmit="return Client.checkStatement(event)">
             <input id="text-input" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder="Enter Text">            
             <button onclick="return Client.checkInput(event)">SubmitInput</button>
         </form>
         <form class="blog-entry-url">
             <input id="text-url" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder="Enter Text">            
             <button onclick="return Client.checkUrl(event)">SubmitURL</button>
         </form>
     <section>

     <section class="form-results">
         <strong>Form Results:</strong>
         <div id="results"></div>
     </section>
 </main>

 <footer>
     <p>This is a footer</p>
 </footer>
</body>`

  const postData = (input1, input2) => { return Promise.resolve({
     text: 'Hello',
     language: 'en',
     categories: [
         {
         label: 'religious festival or holiday - easter',
         code: '12014002',
         confidence: 0.54
         }
     ]
     })
 };
 
 urlValidation('What is going on', postData);
 expect(document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML).toEqual(`<p>Text Data: Testing Input</p><p>Label: religious festival or holiday - easter</p>`)
});
```

The urlValidation function takes in a function as a parameter and then from the json data that is return from the promise adds the values to the DOM.

**urlValidations.js**

```js
const urlValidation = (inputText, callback) => {
    const inputData = {input: inputText};
    callback("http://localhost:8080/classify-url", inputData).then(data =>{
        console.log(data);
        printData(inputData, data);
    });
};
```

The print Data function manipulates the DOM and add the data to the webpage.

**printData.js**

```js
function printData(dataObj, data) {
    console.log(`Data: ${data} DataObj: ${dataObj}`);
    const results = document.getElementById('results');
    const languageSystem = document.createDocumentFragment();
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = `Text Data: ${dataObj.input}`;
    languageSystem.appendChild(p);
    if (data.categories.length == 0) {
        const label = document.createElement('p');
        label.innerHTML = `Label: None`;
        languageSystem.appendChild(label);
    } else {
        data.categories.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element);
            const label = document.createElement('p');
            label.innerHTML = `Label: ${element.label}`;
            languageSystem.appendChild(label);
            console.log(`Label: ${languageSystem.innerHTML}`);
        });
    }

    console.log(data);
    console.log(`Results: ${languageSystem.innerHTML}`);
    results.appendChild(languageSystem);

}
```

When I run the test I'm getting this result back:

```
Expected: "<p>Text Data: Testing Input</p><p>Label: religious festival or holiday - easter</p>"
    Received: ""

      68 |     
      69 |     urlValidation('What is going on', postData);
    > 70 |     expect(document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML).toEqual(`<p>Text Data: Testing Input</p><p>Label: religious festival or holiday - easter</p>`)
         |                                                          ^
      71 |   });

      at Object.toEqual (src/__tests__/testUrl.spec.js:70:58)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.036 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Which is strange since I had a test were I was able to add the json data directly to the printData function and that test is working fine.

I also did a bunch of console.log to see if the json data was being passed in correctly to the printData function, and it seemed like it was this is the result.

```
    console.log
      Label: religious festival or holiday - easter

      at log (src/client/js/checkStatement.js:45:21)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

    console.log
      {
        text: 'Hello',
        language: 'en',
        categories: [
          {
            label: 'religious festival or holiday - easter',
            code: '12014002',
            confidence: 0.54
          }
        ]
      }

      at log (src/client/js/checkStatement.js:49:13)
```

I'm pretty sure doing something wrong, but I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is race condition caused by that there are promises that aren't chained.

`urlValidation` should return a promise:

```
return callback("http://localhost:8080/classify-url", inputData).then(...);
```

Then it can be awaited in a test or any other place that needs to sequentially execute it:

```
await urlValidation('What is going on', postData);
expect(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. You are Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Estus Flask since he was the one that helped me understand that it was a race condition.

So what I had to do change the test to an async test.

```js
test('Testing url Validation', async () => {
....
```

and add an await to wait on the results before running the expected test

```js
await urlValidation('What is going on', postData);
expect(document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML).toEqual(`<p>Text Data: What is going on</p><p>Label: religious festival or holiday - easter</p>`)
```

again credit goes to Estus Flask, thanks for your Help!